# How to include outside jQuery plugin in authored plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, include

I am writing a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) plugin that requires the use of another plugin. Currently I solve this like so:

```
<script src="otherPlugin.js"></script>
<script src="myPlugin.js"></script>
```

And this works fine. However, is it an issue that my plugin can not stand on its own like so?

```
<script src="myPlugin.js"></script>
```

This is my first jQuery plugin, so I'm not really sure if this is bad practice or not. For example, I know when writing a [Perl](http://perl.org/) module the module author includes all modules that they need so that the user doesn't have to worry about it. Is there no similar way to do this in jQuery? (I imagine not, since the user would need to have the file on their server).

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732068/how-to-include-an-external-plugin-inside-of-another-jquery-plugin-being-authored), however this refers to how to include another plugin via a url, which is not what I want.

What is the proper way to use another jQuery plugin with my own? Would simply throwing an error be sufficient if the file is not included? Thanks!

Comment: Depends how you document the requirement, I guess.

Comment: @BenM, I was wondering if maybe this was the case. I was trying to think of plugins I had used that had required other plugins, but I couldn't seem to think of any! Is this how you would handle it?

Comment: I would. In effect, it's no different than saying that your plugin requires jQuery. If the end-user is not able to follow your basic installation instructions and documentation, that's their problem.